# Dirt bike carburetor problems

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor

I just bought a new float needle that fits and it still seem like the tang is not even touching the needle when I press the floater all way in.I have a PJ carb,maybe the floaters are to a pwk carb,maybe not the right size.Can anyone help me out here gas shoots straight out the overflow hose when I cut the fuel on

Comment: Mike G.  Can you edit your question to include an image (or a link to an image stored on a public repository?)  You might consider during the edit to make your sentences more readable.  (hint, the use of a period and question marks make things easier to read.)

Answer (score 4):

Replace the float as well. Sometimes depending upon what material it's made the float can be somewhat soaked with fuel changing the weight of it.

Answer (score 3):

**Needle and seat issue**

Your needle isn't hitting the seat in the float.

- check for physical obstruction of the floats
- always replace the needle and seat as a pair.  They fit together.
- ensure your floats actually float and do not have any holes in them

If you provide more information like the model of the bike we can provide a less generic answer perhaps.  Please include model number of the carb as well as information about the needle you purchased.